# Ubuntu touch OS for desktops

Tags: ubuntu-touch

If I were to build a Desktop PC with a touch screen, Is it possible to run a stable version of Ubuntu Touch on that PC?

If so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

There will be a preview session for Ubuntu Touch as part of the Ubuntu 13.10 desktop release.  Currently you can run the shell (unity 8) by itself inside a window on your desktop, but it won't have all the functionality of Ubuntu Touch on a device.  For that, you'll need to wait for the 13.10 preview session.